# The development server returned response error code: 500 in react native 0.56

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I keep getting this issue every time I run react-native run-android command. I've tried to downgrade versions and have completely reinstalled react native and npm. When I try to clear watchman watches it says "watchman is not recognized" and when I try to run the `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` command it says "rm is not recognized".

I'm using a windows 10 machine and cannot figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug on react-native 0.56 version, try to downgrade version to react-native0.55.4
and also babel dependency babel-preset-react-native: 5.0.0  to babel-preset-react-native : 4.0.0.
run this command

`npm install react-native@0.55.4`

and

`npm install babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0`
It worked for me

check out [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20241) link for more info